# SQL Query, Union Order by like a tree

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, union

Hello I have a query like

```
SELECT 4 AS sortf,XX FROM Table GROUP BY Y
UNION 
SELECT 1 AS sortf,XX FROM Table GROUP BY Y
UNION 
SELECT 2 AS sortf,XX FROM Table GROUP BY Y
UNION
SELECT 3 AS sortf,XX FROM Table GROUP BY Y
ORDER BY 3,2
```

My problem is that the line 2 and 3 ar not ordered like a tree. I tried some other combinations but it did not work.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you want to sort your dataset according to numbers put your code and unions into a common table expression and the use ROW_NUMBER() function to generates row number , something like this :

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 4 AS sortf, productid FROM Production.Products 
    UNION 
    SELECT 1 AS sortf,productid FROM Production.Products
    UNION 
    SELECT 2 AS sortf,productid FROM Production.Products
    UNION
    SELECT 3 AS sortf,productid FROM Production.Products
)
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY productid)  AS SortOrder
FROM CTE
ORDER BY SortOrder
```

Comment: I implemented it and there is a column with that rows 1-16 and sorted. but I have not more possibilities than with the oder by in my example, because i have to specify the order by in the row number command too. the report is correct only line 2 and 3 must be placed in other lines.

Comment: I want the structure like the following. I dont know if it is possible with simple order by.                                                                 -UBD
--RLS
---RLS Kiel
----DetailData
----DetailData
--RWM
---Neuenburg
----DetailData
----DetailData
---Unterlüß
----DetailData
----DetailData